# Why does Dot Net Bundling and minification fail after a while on Azure

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have bundling and minification setup on my website. Each time it is published to Azure (a web app/website) it works fine, but after a while (a few hours) I start to see the individual files shown in source rather than the bundle.

The bundles themselves are still there and still work if I download them
Any ideas what circumstances can cause a bundle to work for a while then stop?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: it wasn't actually Azure related - there was a line of code in an occasionally used admin view

```
System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

I'm not sure why it was there - presumably for debugging, but of course, once that admin view got hit, bundling gets turned off site wide.